# Is there a difference between historical fiction and creative non-fiction?

Tags: creative-writing, genre, historical-fiction, historical

I have seen two similar terms, historical fiction and creative non-fiction. I'm writing some stories that are set during a real time in history, that might mention real events, real people, but that have fictional main characters and a fictional sequence of events within that setting. Or some stories that are about a real historical person and real time, but the dialogue and actual details that must be filled in are made-up to create a fuller story.

Are these two different names of the same thing or completely different?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Creative non-fiction recounts factually-accurate narratives in a literary style. It reads like a story, but it is in fact real history. It will be severely criticised for containing factual inaccuracies, let alone fictional main characters. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_nonfiction))

Historical fiction, on the other hand, is fiction, set in some specific period in the past. The period and its events play a part in the story, but the main characters or their actions are ultimately fictional. *Ivanhoe* and *The Three Musketeers* are famous examples. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_fiction))

Since your main characters are fictional, what you're writing is historical fiction.

Comment: Example of creative non-fiction: *Apollo 13* (which does contain a few factual inaccuracies, but for the most part it sticks pretty close to historical fact).

Comment: What if you recount factually accurate historic events from the perspective of a main character who is fictional but could plausibly have been present at these events, yet weren't named in any historic records because they themselves were too insignificant? Like a maid at the court of Henry VIII or a prison guard at the Bastille during the French revolution? If such a character would recount those events as accurate as historically possible, wouldn't it also be creative non-fiction?

Comment: @Philipp That sounds like "literary style".

Comment: This gets a little confusing - looks like "_fictionalization_" process would produce "creative _non_-fiction"?